# How to Sum multiple lines in sql

Tags: sql, summary

I have multiple lines of data all sharing the same Company id.

Is there a way to 'sum' all the amounts to give me one line of data per company id using SQL Server Management Studio 2005?

For example I currently have the below data......

```
Company_Name   Company_ID   Amount
Company 6         10024   120
Company 6         10024   569
Company 6         10024    53
Company 6         10024   100
Company 6         10024   564
Company 7         10638  9500
Company 7         10638   105
Company 7         10638   624
```

What i would like to try and get is.......

```
Company_ Name   Company_ID     Amount 
Company 6        10024         1406
Company 7        10638        10229
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Any advice pointing me the right way would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: There are no "lines" in SQL. You can call it {records,tuples,rows} (with slightly different meaning) but not "lines". What you want is called "aggregation". Look up SUM in your fine manual. SUM() is one of the "aggregate functions".

Comment: @wildplasser: Actually, what they require is "summarization", slightly different meaning ;)

Comment: Note your table is not fully normalized.

Comment: cheers for all your help.  I have sorted it.  thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT Company_Name, Company_ID, SUM(Amount) 
FROM TableName GROUP BY Company_Name, Company_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Company_Name, Company_ID, sum(Amount)
FROM your table
GROUP BY Company_Name, Company_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
SELECT Company_Name, Company_ID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM Companies
GROUP BY Company_Name, Company_ID;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/996c3/3).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Company_Name, Company_ID, sum(Amount)
FROM table
group by Company_Name, Company_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `SUM` function.

```
SELECT Company_Name, Company_ID, SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Company_Name, Company_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH T ( Company_Name, Company_ID, Amount )
     AS
     (
      SELECT 'Company 6', '10024', 120 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 6', '10024', 569 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 6', '10024', 53 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 6', '10024', 100 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 6', '10024', 564 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 7', '10638', 9500 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 7', '10638', 105 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Company 7', '10638', 624 
     )
SELECT DISTINCT Company_Name, Company_ID, 
       SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Company_ID) AS total_amount
  FROM T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
    select Company_Name   , Company_ID   ,sum(Amount) as 'Amount' from Company group by 
Company_Name,Company_ID   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tempTable
(
    Id bigint,
    Title varchar(100),
    Amount money
)
insert into #TempTable(Title,Id,Amount)
Values
('Company 6',         10024,   120),
('Company 6',         10024,   569),
('Company 6',         10024,    53),
('Company 6',         10024,   100),
('Company 6',         10024,   564),
('Company 7',         10638,  9500),
('Company 7',         10638,   105),
('Company 7',         10638,   624)


select Title, Sum(Amount)Amount from #TempTable
group by Title,ID

drop Table #TempTable
```