# Fastest way to add data: MySQL or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

My goal is to get the sum of data the fastest way possible, whether that is done in a MySQL query or when processing it in JavaScript after I get the data. Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total,
    SUM(ICCID1State = '14' AND ICCID1Carrier = '0' OR ICCID2State = '14' AND ICCID2Carrier = '0') 'AT&T Activated',
    SUM(ICCID1State = '15' AND ICCID1Carrier = '0' OR ICCID2State = '15' AND ICCID2Carrier = '0') 'AT&T Not Activated',
    SUM(ICCID1Carrier = 0 OR ICCID2Carrier = 0) 'AT&T Total',
    SUM(ICCID1State = '14' AND ICCID1Carrier = '1' OR ICCID2State = '14' AND ICCID2Carrier = '1') 'Verizon Activated',
    SUM(ICCID1State = '15' AND ICCID1Carrier = '1' OR ICCID2State = '15' AND ICCID2Carrier = '1') 'Verizon Not Activated',
    SUM(ICCID1Carrier = 1 OR ICCID2Carrier = 1) 'Verizon Total'
FROM myTable
WHERE DealerKey = ?
```

Would that be faster than just fetching all the data and then adding it using JavaScript?

Comment: please read this : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600587/how-to-sum-multiple-lines-in-sql

Comment: @Sirmyself will do! Thanks!

Comment: @Sirmyself So I've looked into those and neither of them talks about speed. My current query works great, I'm just not sure if its the fastest/best way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: You should generally prefer to do things in SQL if you can.

Comment: @joshbang they don't talk about speed, they just show how to do what you actually want to do

Comment: As 4castle mentioned, When you can, I would do it in SQL. If possible, even take that one step futher to create stored procedures that, when called, do the logic on the SQL side and just give you back the result.

Comment: @4castle Even if it will have to run those sum functions for thousands(Eventually hundreds of thousands)  of rows? I just dont know how long those functions are compared to just adding a couple numbers in javascript after I have the data

Comment: @joshbang The more rows there are, the more important it is that you do it in SQL. The database engine won't have to send tons of data.

Comment: If you're going to downvote the question, please explain why you downvoted. It is an honest question and seems to comply with stack overflow's "How to ask a question" template. Thanks!

Comment: @4castle You're awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database operations will pretty much always be faster for this type of stuff.  Relational databases are made for this and the engines are very, very fast.  With top level languages (JavaScript, any others...), you must first fetch all the data then "manually" tally it up.

Do some google searches for "Set based" vs "Cursor Based" (or "RBAR" - Row by Agonizing Row) processing in SQL (pick your database engine: MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, MSSQL - doesn't matter, all operating principles are the same).

When you use a higher level programming language, you're essentially using cursor-based/RBAR processing.

Always understand what you're asking your application components to do for you, and when you understand that, you can make a reasonable decision as to which will be better.

Comment: I'll go look those up right now! Thank you!! I love learning new stuff and I've never heard of "Set Based" Or "Cursor Based" before!

Comment: RBAR will probably be easier to find, and RBAR is basically the same thing as cursor-based operations.  Close enough for what you need anyway... "why is RBAR bad for performance" or something...

Comment: That helped A LOT. Thanks a bunch!